# python3 setup.py install is failing (RHEL 8)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, setuptools, distutils

**Issue:**

```
#python3 setup.py install
```

**is failing**

**Environment:  RHEL 8 UBI container**

---

I have a setup.py that looks like this: (any pointers or updates on this setup.py would be appreciated)

```
import setuptools

print('python/setup.py')

setuptools.setup(
      name="process_data",
      version="1.0",
      description="desc",
      author="FirstName LastName",
      author_email="dude@abides.abide",
      url="https://some.com",
      packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
)
```

---

I have a directory structure like so (`<some>.py` in every directory, along with `__init__.py`):

```
python/
 setup.py
 <dir>/__init__.py
 <dir>/__init__.py
 <dir4>/__init__.py
 <dir4>/<sub-dir1>/__init__.py
 <dir4>/<sub-dir1>/<sub-dir>__init__.py
```

---

I want code in each of these directories to be part of a module package so I can import, nested however deep.

---

I'm doing this:

```
#cd python
#python3 setup.py install
```

---

**I get this error:**

```
python/setup.py
running install
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/test-easy-install-1625.write-test

    [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/test-easy-install-1625.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/

This directory does not currently exist.  Please create it and try again, or
choose a different installation directory (using the -d or --install-dir
option).
```

---

**Questions:**

**Where is this coming from:**  `test-easy-install-1625.write-test`   ?  (so confused as to what this is)

On my system, indeed this directory does not exist (**why is** python3 setup.py install looking there? what told it to look there?):
`/usr/local/lib/python3.6`

There is nothing in my `setup.py` to indicate to look there.

---

I looked all over, and it looks like my /site-packages/ directory is here (where other modules are installed, when I ran pip)

```
`/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/`
```

---

**How do I fix this?**

Thank you, I so badly need to get this working right away.  I have been working on Windows, and `>python setup.py install` simply works there.

Are there any env variables I should have setup?

I simply installed python with:  `dnf -y install python36` that's it.  (the latest version available in any RHEL 8 package repo for installation).

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I have landed into the same issue and no workaround can avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same error and I was able to fix it by creating a symbolic link.  I accept someone else maybe able to offer a more elegant solution and I welcome it.

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/lib/python3.6
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages /usr/local/lib/python3.6/
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you had enter python command mode, if you don't, the following commands are needed, notice to set variable Path and PythonPath of yours:

```
setlocal
set env_name=python3.6
set Path=C:\Users\s41167\Miniconda3\envs\%env_name%;C:\Users\s41167\Miniconda3\envs\%env_name%\Scripts;%Path%
set PythonPath=C:\Users\s41167\Miniconda3\envs\%env_name%\Lib\site-packages
cd C:\Users\s41167\Documents\%env_name%
cmd.exe /K activate %env_name%
```

if you enter python command mode, you can use pip to insall the package:

```
pip install <package location> --target <install location> --upgrade
```

below is my install command and result:

```
(python3.6) C:\Users\s41167\Documents\python3.6>pip install ./python_package --t
arget ./target --upgrade
Processing c:\users\s41167\documents\python3.6\python_package
Building wheels for collected packages: process-data
  Building wheel for process-data (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for process-data: filename=process_data-1.0-cp36-none-any.whl si
ze=1721 sha256=ef5eaf061000f30d472e5dde268694733e40a3f8a4a29fa78faec69f125443c9
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\s41167\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-
v6lt_ndp\wheels\61\01\f5\07e0760baa10d63e1c43b37eadbb55b79828f4fe337209026a
Successfully built process-data
Installing collected packages: process-data
Successfully installed process-data-1.0

(python3.6) C:\Users\s41167\Documents\python3.6>
```

and the file arrangement:

```
.\python_package
  __init__.py
  setup.py
                \directory
                 __init__.py
                \directory4
                 __init__.py
                            \sub_dirctory1
                             __init__.py
```

Answer (score 0):

**in Linux use**

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

**in windows use**

```
    python setup.py install
```

**or**

```
python3 setup.py install
```